# Bootcamp and wireless usb keyboard: How to boot with Mac os

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, startup, mac-mini

I have a Mac mini. I installed windows 7 with bootcamp and now windows 7 is the default OS.

My problem is that it doens't seem to recognize my keypress during the boot (I have a logitech usb wireless keyboard/mouse)

I was wondering if I can achieve to start in Mac OS with this keyboard.

I know its enough to press option on boot to get the selection window. But i tried with ctrl, windows, shift, alt, alt+gr and none of them will prompt the selector.

Any ideas? (maybe a bootable usb?)

-EDIT-

I've heard of http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/

but it doesn't seem to be possible to set it up from windows..

Comment: Depending upon [which model of Mac Mini](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3476) you have, it might recognize paired bluetooth keyboards during the EFI boot process - but I'll give a general answer since you didn't specify which hardware you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into windows and use the Bootcanp control panel to set the next boot to be Mac OS X.

From http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5639 :

> **Startup questions
>
>   How do I choose which operating system will start up my Mac?**
>   After running Boot Camp Assistant and installing
>   Microsoft Windows and Boot Camp drivers, press and hold the Option
>   (Alt) key while you start up your Mac to switch between Microsoft
>   Windows and OS X.
>
> Use the Startup Disk Control Panel in Windows or OS X Startup Disk
>   System Preferences to set the default operating system to use each
>   time the computer starts up.

Or you can get any old USB keyboard and hold the option key.

Comment: I don't seem to have this control panel. I tried to download almost all the bootcamp utilities from here: And they all said that its not for my current version :S

Comment: Assuming you have the latest BootCamp, the drivers download from OS X Side, so if you are missing that program, a physical keyboard may be needed to move forward with an incomplete BootCamp install.